# What is the Response packet of FCM Http v1 API

Tags: spring-boot, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, microservices

I am developing microservices using springboot and wanted to use FCM to send push notifications to a particular device from one of my Rest API's. To develop this endpoint however, I need to prepare a outbound swagger that will highlight the request and response packet of the FCM HTTP V1 API.
I know the request format as it is available in the documentation but i am unable to find or understand what the response packet will be. Currently i have an empty firebase project so i don't have a device registered to that project. Hence, i will never get success yet. Please can someone let me know how the response packet looks like  in a success scenario? Sending a request to the topic returns a different response than Sending to a specific device using the devices fcm token. I will be using the latter. Please assist. Thanks

I have sent a request using postman to a fcm token of another uat project of my client. Since that token is not part of my current firebase project i get an error and i beleive i understand what the error response will look like. Success however, i do not know.